# Is it possible to switch back to older app version on appstore?

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

Update for my app on appstore was just accepted by Apple (and held by developer==me because i used this option when submitting app to review).
If i release this version to appstore, is it possible to switch back to older version (also approved by apple) without submitting it again to review?

Comment: i think you will even have to increase (minor) version number even though you'll be switching to the older code

Comment: Meccan please make this an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible. You can submit the old version if you have your source code for old version. You can change the version to new one and compile source, submit to App store. I don't think they wont review it.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible to revert to a previously submitted version.